# What do Oracle redo log records look like?

Tags: oracle, logging, cdc

What do Oracle redo log records look like? I've tried searching everywhere I can think of, and have been unable to find any examples.

Are they text logs that are human readable? (And straightforward to parse?) Or are they complicated and require specialized tools to parse?

I'm interested in when a given set of tables has any changed column values, new rows, or deleted rows. I would likely write an aws lambda function to process these events - assuming that's a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: Redo logs are a proprietary, binary format. They are not human readable. There is a Log Miner utility that allows you to see the content, but it would not allow you to build a function on top of it. It sounds like what you want is basic auditing, which can be accomplished using Oracle's audit feature, or perhaps using triggers (depending on exactly what you're trying to do).

Comment: Is CDC any more parse-able / any different? I actually want to stream changes over to elasticsearch, with some transformation required in between.

Comment: Oracle no longer has a default CDC feature. Their solution is for you to buy their GoldenGate product and use that to stream data changes into heterogenous targets. You could attempt to build a custom CDC using triggers and `DBMS_AQ` or `UTL_TCP` calls or some such, but there's a fair amount of risk with that approach in terms of performance impact, data integrity issues, and just the complexity of building and maintaining the custom code from scratch.

Comment: In similar situations I have had to pull data into the target environment (Splunk, in my case) using the included JDBC SQL interface, rather than push changes from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May we assume you did google "Oracle redolog internals" or similar did you?
There is a treasure trove of information out there.

In particular Julian Dyke's (now retired) material are always great:
http://www.juliandyke.com/Presentations/Presentations.php
http://www.juliandyke.com/Presentations/RedoInternals.ppt

Even just glancing over this should make it clear that it is a monumental, error-prone, task to do tis properly and supported for years to come, as per 'pmdba'

There are several commercial tools who have done the work, and while they typically have a big price tag that are a 'steal' compared to building your own except for the most rudimentary functions.

Golden Gate is of course Oracle own solution. Expensive and most future proof.
LOGminer solution were/are great but that is deprecated and will run into trouble with recent versions/features

Personally, having worked for years during its development and early deployment, I am a big fan of what is now Qlik Replicate - originally from Attunity. It offers 'any' source (including Oracle) to any database (including cloud stuff) CDC and full-load with an easy UI, optional JSON descriptions, and a host of performance and functional features. Limited, SQLlite function based, transformations are available.

Good luck!